# How to hook up an LED strip to an Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, rgb-led

I want to add 6 LEDs  under my Arduino case and have the Arduino Uno pulsate the colors. How do I do this?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/klYLoVv.jpg]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which part of your code is not working? Can you post your code and a schematic? Thanks.

Comment: i dont have a code or schematic that is my problem

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-led-strips/usage

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what they are and how much you don't know :-)

I'd suggest starting off by looking at the tutorials for [NeoPixels](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/overview) and [DotStars](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-dotstar-leds/overview) on Adafruit's site – that should give you a general idea of how things work. Then take a look at the [FastLED](http://fastled.io) library, it supports a large number of LED strips and has some decent examples.

The FastLED examples that will show up in the Arduino IDE after you have installed the library.

Once you've gotten as far as identifying the strip you have and reading some of the basic tutorials and trying out some of the examples you'll either know how to do it or have some much more specific questions to ask.

OK, after looking at the [info on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MA397GI) and looking more closely at the strip (and the price). I don't think these are individually addressable LEDs. More likely the RGB lines are grounds. So what you would do is to provide a +12V supply on the 12V line and ground one or more the RGB lines to turn on that LED. You could probably control brightness with PWM (pulse width modulation, turning them on and off quickly). The catch here is that the current draw will be more than the Arduino can sink and it's at 12V – two quick ways to kill your board in one tidy package.

You'll need to do more research on this to get the details right, but I think you could use a transistor to do the switching (to protect your Arduino for the 12 V and from the current necessary to drive the LEDs). You would connect an Arduino pin to the base of the transistor to control it. You'd need to select a transistor that can handle the current of all of the LEDs of that color. As a guess I'd figure 60 mA per LED at full brightness (for each color) – this is based on NeoPixels running at 5 V so I could be way off.

If I'm right that these are not individually addressable then the programming would be relatively easy – just turn on the output to turn on the color.

I'd start off by cutting off a strip of the LEDs to experiment with. Use the 12V supply that came with them and see what happens when you connect 12 V to the 12V line and ground one of the color lines. It doesn't look like there is a resistor to limit current, so you should add one to hold the current down. I *think* the LEDs would be wired in parallel, so you'd be looking at needing to supply 6 times the individual LED current. To be safe you could start at around 20 mA and use a 100Ω 1W resistor – you can find an LED resistor calculator [here](http://ledcalc.com), be sure to select the parallel calculation and use a low current to start with to be safe.

Once you know that the strip works the way you think it does, try adding a transistor to control each color. Then when you've got that working, hook up to the Arduino. Just remember that you will also need to respect the Arduino's current and voltage limits on the digital pins.

Comment: what do you mean identifying the strip?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00MA397GI?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00

Comment: @laxus There are two ways to control your strip. a) You somehow make the Arduino behave as the controller or b) You send the Infrared commands with your arduino to emulate the remote.